# What is the advantage of using AST & Tree walker for translating a DSL instead of directly parsing & translating objects from parser grammar?

Tags: python, antlr3

I am creating a Domain Specific Language using Antlr3. So far, I have directly translated the parsed objects from inside the parser grammar. Going through the examples of AST and Tree Walker, i came to know that they are normally used to divide the grammar into hierarchical tree and translate objects from the nodes. Currently i am also  doing the same sort of action using parser grammar where i translate objects from each sub-rule. I would be more than happy to know the advantages of using AST & Tree walker over just using parser grammars. Thanking you in advanced.

Comment: This may disappoint, but to do serious code generation for a DSL, "tree walking" isn't any better answer than "parser grammars.  See my essay, "Life after parsing" http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/LifeAfterParsing.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One advantage of using tree parsers is that you can organize them into multiple passes.  For some translation work I did I was able to use seven passes and separate logical steps into their own pass.  One pass did expression analysis, one did control flow analysis, others used that analysis to eliminate dead code or to simplify the translation for special cases.

I personally like using tree grammars for the same reason I like using parsers for text grammars.  It allows me to use rules to organize the parsing context.  It's easy to do things like structure rules to recognize a top-level expression versus a subexpression if you need to distinguish between them for recognition purposes.  All of the attribute and context management you use in regular parsers can apply to tree parsers.